# Extracting the timestamp from a video clip

Tags: video, timestamp, avi

I have an organizing need for my video clips, and would like to rename them using the time stamp of the video. Since not all sources record the Modified date, I would like to be able to extract the timestamp of the first frame. Ideally, I could use a method similar to the existing framework method for images:

```
    BitmapSource img = BitmapFrame.Create(fs);
    BitmapMetadata md = (BitmapMetadata)img.Metadata;
    DateTime shot = DateTime.Parse(md.DateTaken);
```

Is there an easy way to do this, or maybe use the ffmpeg library or any other library to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Most multimedia container files including AVI does not record capture time as timestamp. Usually, timestamp of any frame is usually the time difference between that frame and the first frame. So unless file format records capture time as meta data seperately, there is no easy way to extract captured time from such files.